# Published WCF service on azurewebsites.net does not return sql record

Tags: vb.net, wcf, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to create an API using visual basic for an iPhone app. To do this, I have written a WCF web service which runs perfectly fine on localhost.

Calling: getTimeSheetRecord/{deviceID} returns

[image: getTimeSheetRecord Result]

**The image above shows that the code is able to connect to the SQL database and returns the record.**

As I need to be able to access the API from outside my company network, I am required to host it to be accessible from anywhere. Therefore I have used Build -> Publish to create Microsoft Azure App Server in Visual Studio 2015. Everything went well, until I ran my function to return a database record. It does not give me the same result as in localhost, in fact, I think it does not even have a connection to the database. Please see the image below:

[image: http://jsonwebserviceapi.azurewebsites.net/Service1.svc/getTimeSheetRecord/Apple]

**The image above is the published WCF that I am trying to get to work. This does not return the record as it did shown in the previous image. The code is not any different since all I did was publish it through visual studio 2015.**

My WCF is connected to the MS SQL Server that is running in an Azure VM. 
This is the code within my WCF to connect to the database:

```js
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Module modGlobal

    'Global Database Objects
    Public uDBase As ADODB.Connection
    Public uCommand As ADODB.Command
    Public bConnection As Boolean
    Public bActive As Boolean = True
    Public sErrDescription As String

    Public Sub OpenConnection()
        '** Open Database Connection

        ' Error Checking
        On Error GoTo Err_OpenConnection

        ' Open Database Connection
        uDBase = New ADODB.Connection
        uDBase.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Initial Catalog=BMSSaltire;Data Source=tcp:xxxxxxxx.cloudapp.net,xxxxx;User ID=xxxxxUser;Password=xxxxx"
        uDBase.CommandTimeout = 0
        uDBase.Open()
Err_OpenConnection:
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then

            CloseConnection()
If

    End Sub

    Sub CloseConnection()
        '** Close Database Connection
        uDBase = Nothing
        uCommand = Nothing

    End Sub

End Module
```

And this is my Service.svc.vb

```js
 Public Function GetTimeSheetRecord(ByVal deviceID As String) As List(Of wsTimeSheet) Implements ServiceInterface.GetTimeSheetRecord


 Dim results As List(Of wsTimeSheet) = New List(Of wsTimeSheet)
 Try

   Dim uRecSnap As ADODB.Recordset

 If uDBase Is Nothing Then
 OpenConnection()
 bConnection = True
 End If


 uCommand = New ADODB.Command
 With uCommand
   .ActiveConnection = uDBase
   .CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc
   .CommandTimeout = 0
   .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@DeviceID", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 32, deviceID))
   .CommandText = "TimeSheet_LoadRecord"
 uRecSnap = .Execute
 End With

 Do Until uRecSnap.EOF
 Dim uAction = New wsTimeSheet
 uAction.DeviceID = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("ActionDate").Value), "", uRecSnap("ActionDate").Value)
 results.Add(uAction)
 uRecSnap.MoveNext()
 Loop

 uRecSnap = Nothing


 Catch ex As Exception
   ' Catch Error
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
 End If

 Finally
   ' CleanUp
            If bConnection Then CloseConnection()

        End Try

        Return results
    End Function
```

Also when I try to publish, in Settings it says under Databases that "No databases found in the project".

**EDIT 08/03/2016**
I have tried to see if it is any different when I publish it to the localhost IIS, but even then it does not return the records from the SQL database tables. It works fine when I debug it on Visual Studio using the virtual directory that I have set up under "Web" in Settings. Does it have anything to do with the Web.config?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify whether your code is able to even connect to your SQL Database. Also please clarify whether your code, when running locally, was able to connect to your SQL database VM in Azure (or if it was connecting to a local database).

Comment: @DavidMakogon The code is able to connect to the SQL database when I debug it through visual studio (local), but it is unable to do so once I have published it. I have not created the SQL database on the Azure portal hoping it would connect to the Server as I have provided the TCP server data source to the Ms SQL server running in Azure VM.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Today I have come across a post which is similar to my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662610/connecting-existing-asp-net-application-to-azure-sql-server-vm-without-sdk

My SQL server is in an Azure VM which I am trying to access through my WCF. There however is no connection and I am unsure what needs to be done so that the WCF published in http://jsonwebserviceapi.azurewebsites.net/Service1.svc is able to connect to the SQL database in an azure VM and return the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my WCF working. There were a few small adjustments I had to do in my Web.config and change my ADODB reference property Copy Local = True and Embed Interop Type = False.

This is my Web.config file. Hope someone finds it useful.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <!--<add key="saltireServiceUrl" value="http://[sitename].azurewebsites.net/Service1.svc" />-->
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="JSONWebService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="JSONWebService.Service1Behaviour">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="JSONWebService.ServiceInterface" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="JSONWebService.Service1Behaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehaviour">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix="http://[sitename].azurewebsites.net/"/>
      </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and put the connection string as a setting in your cloud project. 
Right-click on the properties of the project
Select "Settings"
Click "Add Setting"

By the way, does your connection string in the code match the one you can see in the Azure portal?

Hope it helps.
/Fredrik

Comment: I have added the connection string to my Web.config and my project settings. It still does not return the records. 

By the way, I have not transferred the database that is currently running on the Azure VM to the Azure portal. Is it not possible for the WCF to open the connection to the VM Ms SQL Management Server?

Comment: Can you clarify "I have not transferred the database that is currently running on the Azure VM to the Azure portal"? Where is your DB located currently and where are you planning to move it?

Comment: @GandhaliSamant I have read many articles that requires the database to be created in the Azure Portal and then build a connection. The way I am trying to do this is by opening a connection to the database within "Service1.svc.vb". So far it is unable to probably open the connection and return the records. I wonder if that explains anything.